# two months while selecting a date in date-picker in bootstrap

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, datepicker

I am working on a website in website when I select I want two months to be displayed while selecting any start date and end date.

At this moment, on my [domain](http://ferhan.ferohost.com/) only one month is displayed on start date and end date.

The code which I have used in order to make datepicker work for start date and end date are:

```
<script>
$("#startdate_datepicker").datepicker();
$("#enddate_datepicker" ).datepicker();
</script>
```

**Problem Statement:**

I am wondering what changes I should make in script two months calendar get displayed while selecting start date and end date.

I tried with the following code but somehow it doesn't seem to work.

```
<script>
$("#startdate_datepicker").datepicker({ numberOfMonths: [2, 3] });
$("#enddate_datepicker" ).datepicker({ numberOfMonths: [2, 3] });
</script>
```

Comment: Is this the datepicker from bootstrap? To my knowledge it doesnt show a range of 2, if i am not mistaken. The jquery datepicker on the other hand does. it listens to the variable `numberOfMonths: 2` (without the brackets). Else try something like this http://www.daterangepicker.com/

Comment: Yes, it is from Bootstrap and I was also thinking the same that we can't do that in Bootstrap but I wasn't sure.  I am wondering what changes i need to do in the code. If you press CTRL+U (I am pretty sure, you know that), you can see all the code behind it.

Comment: @Dorvalla Something like this:

    `<script>
$("#startdate_datepicker").datepicker({ numberOfMonths: 2 });
$("#enddate_datepicker" ).datepicker({ numberOfMonths:  2 });
</script>`

Answer (score 1):

Current is:

```
<script>
$("#startdate_datepicker").datepicker({ numberOfMonths: [2, 3] });
$("#enddate_datepicker" ).datepicker({ numberOfMonths: [2, 3] });
</script>
```

Change to:

```
<script>
$("#startdate_datepicker").datepicker({ numberOfMonths: [1, 2] });
$("#enddate_datepicker" ).datepicker({ numberOfMonths: [1, 2] });
</script>
```

Here in `numberOfMonths: [1, 2]`, `1` is row and `2` number of months.

To change the color to orange, use below CSS:

```
.ui-widget-header {
  border: 1px solid #FFA500;
  background : #FFA500;
}

.ui-state-default, .ui-widget-content .ui-state-default, .ui-widget-header .ui-state-default {
    border: 1px solid #FFA500;
  background : #FFA500;
}
```

Comment: I tried with Option 1, it didn't work. I used this [way](http://jsbin.com/ibile4/1/edit?css,output) to make it work and its working fine for me. I have one quick regarding that. At this moment, the calendar color is aqua.Is there any way we can change to orange ?

Comment: @user5447339 I am updating my answer for how to make it orange color.